# How to include Symfony Bundle into almost ready project

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, shopping-cart

I have existing project in Symfony which is almost ready. The project contains login, registration, every logged in user can add products in specific category etc.. I am new in symfony and i don't know which cart bundle is the best and the easiest to use. I want to include it into my project with current functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using ready-to-use Symfony Commerce projects, such as [Aimeos](https://aimeos.org/) or [Sylius](http://sylius.org/)